# WPF: Display PDF File using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, path, browser

I have a pdf file Placed in the Resource folder.
I want to display the PDF File using WebBrowser control.
The Main Problem is to find the relative path of the PDF and convert it to absolute, since the WebBrowser dosnt support relative Path.

so far I have the following code(*simplified version*):

```
string GuidePath = "../Resources/Guide/LogViwer User Manual.pdf";
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(GuidePath);
Uri GuideURI = new Uri(fullPath, UriKind.Absolute);
Browser.Navigate(GuideURI);
```

'Browser' is aninstance of a WebBrowser.

The Exeption I get is:

> Connot find ...Path... Make sure the path and Internet address is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the file Properties "Copy to output" must be set to "copy if newer"
and the Code must be edited to:

```
string GuidePath = @"./Resources/Guide/LogViwer User Manual.pdf";
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `WebBrowser` class's documentation, the Navigate method expects a URI, not a filesystem path. You should be able to sort that out thanks to the `Uri` class:

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(fullPath));
```

Although I haven't tested that so no promises.

Comment: **NO**. It has also an overload takes _string_ parameter. Check it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40x214wa.aspx

Comment: @SonerGönül yes a string with a URL in it. Last I checked, GetFullPath doesn't return a URL...